# Call a method inside data in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mqtt, arrow-functions, paho

I trying to do a MQTT connection with Paho in vue.js, but I have some problems with the options object.

```js
Vue.component('componente', {
    template: `<div></div>`,
    data: () => ({
        mqtt: null,
        options: {
            timeout: 3,
            onSuccess: () => this.success(), //here is the problem
            onFailure: () => this.failure(),
        },
        host: "10.0.0.11",
        port: 8083,
        client: "WebClient",
        topic: "mqtt"
    }),
    methods: {
    success: () => {
        console.log("Conexion completa");
        this.mqtt.subscribe(this.topic);
    },
    failure: (msg) => {
        console.log("error");
        console.error(msg);
    },
    message(msg){
        console.log("Mensaje " + msg.payloadString);
    },
    connect(){
        console.log("conectando");
        this.mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(this.host,this.port,this.client);
        this.mqtt.onMessageArrived = this.message;
        this.mqtt.connect(this.options);
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.connect();
  }
});
```

This do nothing, the `success` method is never called. But if I change, `.connect` for this, is work.

```js
this.mqtt.connect({onSuccess: () => {this.mqtt.subscribe(this.topic)}});
```

Previously, I had many problems calling the function on data, gave me errors like "success is not a function". Now, this not show any error.

Edit: The next code work, but the subscribe function do nothing

```js
this.mqtt.connect({onSuccess: this.success});
```

Comment: Wouldn't `this` refer to the local scope which would be the new function? I think you're trying to achieve `onSuccess: this.success`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change `data` to *not* use an arrow function, ie

```js
data () {
  return {
    mqtt: null,
    options: {
      timeout: 3,
      onSuccess: () => this.success(),
      onFailure: () => this.failure(),
    },
    host: "10.0.0.11",
    port: 8083,
    client: "WebClient",
    topic: "mqtt"
  }
}
```

None of your methods should be using arrow functions either. Make them all normal object methods.

```js
methods: {
  success () {
    console.log("Conexion completa");
    this.mqtt.subscribe(this.topic);
  },
  // etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks again Phil, jaja, is the second time that you help me. You solved all my problems, is working perfectly. (note: "jaja" is "haha" in Spanish)

Comment: @DrakoPD De nada (No hablo español, pero Google Translate sí)